# pandas: unstacking DataFrame to Series causes NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and want to unstack it, yielding a series `x` and a series `y` with `time` as the index and `value` as the data:

```
   var  time  value
0    x     0     11
1    y     0    123
2    x     1     12
3    y     1    124
4    x     2     13
5    y     2    125
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'time': [0,0,1,1,2,2],
        'var': list('xyxyxy'),
        'value': [11,123,12,124,13,125]})

for col in ['x', 'y']:
    s = pd.Series(
            data=df.loc[df['var'] == col, 'value'],
            index=df.loc[df['var'] == col, 'time'],
            name=col)
    print(s)
```

This is the output:

```
time
0    11.0
1     NaN
2    12.0
Name: x, dtype: float64

time
0      NaN
1    123.0
2      NaN
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

But I expect the series to be

```
time
0    11.0
1    12.0 
2    13.0
Name: x, dtype: float64

time
0    123.0
1    124.0
2    125.0
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Obviously pandas doesn't align the `time`-axis correctly to the `value`-axis. To my understanding each `.loc` should just return the corresponding 3 elements and assemble them together as index and data for the newly constructed series.

1. Why isn't this happening?
2. What would be the easiest way to get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve this as @Wen pointed out. Incase you are wondering whats wrong with your code, you are passing a series as data and index, pass an array instead.

```
for v in df['var'].unique():
    s = pd.Series(
        data=df.loc[df['var'] == v, 'value'].values,
        index=df.loc[df['var'] == v, 'time'].values,
        name=col)
    print(s)

0    11
1    12
2    13
Name: y, dtype: int64
0    123
1    124
2    125
Name: y, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Even though @W-B's `df.pivot` is a nice solution, I accepted this one because it's closer to the question and also explains why my code didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is `pivot` problem

```
s=df.pivot(*df.columns)
s
Out[56]: 
time    0    1    2
var                
x      11   12   13
y     123  124  125

#s['y'],s['x']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why putting a Series as your data gives you that result, but I can answer your second question

2. What would be the easiest way to get my desired result?

You can convert your data to a list to get the desired result.

```
for col in ['x', 'y']:
    s = pd.Series(
            data=df.loc[df['var'] == col, 'value'].tolist(),
            index=df.loc[df['var'] == col, 'time'],
            name=col)
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
time
0    11
1    12
2    13
Name: x, dtype: int64
time
0    123
1    124
2    125
Name: y, dtype: int64
```

Here is another way similar to the answer submitted by @Wen (and more elegant):

```
df_new = pd.pivot_table(data=df, columns='var', index='time', values='value')
```

Output:

```
var    x    y
time         
0     11  123
1     12  124
2     13  125
```

Then you can call `df_new['x']` or `df_new['y']`.